# Redirect issue jmeter for 301 and 302

Tags: jmeter, redirect

I fired one URL on which redirection is expected but I am getting different response code in jmeter and on using devtools that is f12.

Example
Fired http://test.com on chrome, on using f12, i can see response code as 301 and in second line it displays 200 as successful redirection happened.
But, when same URL fired through jmeter, i got response code as 302(Found)
Right now, i have used HTTP request

- Implementaion: No client selection(default),
- GET,
- Protcol - http and proxy server details.

Can you please let us know why we are able to see difference in response code when we fire that URL directly on chrome(301) and through jmeter(302)

Comment: http://test.com is one of the sample URL, not the exact one.

Comment: I think you specified **https://**... in Chrome, this is why result is different

Comment: Check the "Follow Redirects" checkbox in the HTTP sampler. You will be able to see both the response code. Let me know if it works for you. 

Thanks!

Comment: Kiril, I have used http in browser and same in HTTP request cnfiguration in jmeter. But getting, different response code.

Comment: Naveen, when  I have checked follow redirects as true then it writes only 200 that is redirected URL and response code. In view rsult tree, it displays only one response. Can you please let me know how i can see both responses -301/302 and 200 for one request.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that "Follow Redirects" is checked in your [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request):

[image]

Comment: Yeah same i have done but not able to see two responses. On checking Follow redirects, it writes only 200 response code in result tree for redirected URL. Am i missing something?